# difference between android:collapseColumns and android:shrinkColumns of tableLayout

Tags: android, xml

I am new in android development. I was reading TableLayout, Which have three major attributes

android:stretchColumns, 
android:collapseColumns & android:shrinkColumns.

After Some Research I got what exaclty meant by android:strechColumns but i am confused between collapseColumns and shrinkColumns. The official docs Saying.

android:shrinkColumns

The zero-based index of the columns to shrink. The column indices must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices are ignored. You can shrink all columns by using the value "*" instead. Note that a column can be marked stretchable and shrinkable at the same time.

android:collapseColumns

The zero-based index of the columns to collapse. The column indices must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices are ignored.

What is exactly mean by **shrink** and **collapse** .Could anyone tell me what is difference between them?

Answer (score 4):

- android:stretchColumns

  The zero-based index of the columns to stretch. The column indices must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices are ignored. You can stretch all columns by using the value "*" instead. Note that a column can be marked stretchable and shrinkable at the same time.
- android:shrinkColumns

  The zero-based index of the columns to shrink. The column indices must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices are ignored. You can shrink all columns by using the value "*" instead. Note that a column can be marked stretchable and shrinkable at the same time.
- android:collapseColumns

  The zero-based index of the columns to collapse. The column indices must be separated by a comma: 1, 2, 5. Illegal and duplicate indices are ignored.

  ```
  <TableLayout  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:stretchColumns="*"
  android:background="@color/grey">
  <TableRow>
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:background="@color/red"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:text="0" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:background="@color/green"
          android:text="1" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:background="@color/blue"
          android:text="2" />
  </TableRow>


  <TableRow>
      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="0"
          android:background="@color/red"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:text="0" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="1"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:background="@color/green"
          android:text="1" />

      <TextView
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_column="2"
          android:textColor="@android:color/white"
          android:textSize="30dp"
          android:background="@color/blue"
          android:text="2" />
    </TableRow>   
   </TableLayout>
  ```

Explanations:

> `android:stretchColumns="*"`

[image]

Means it stretch all columns equally according table layout width

> `android:shrinkColumns="*"`

[image]

Means it shrink  all columns

> `android:shrinkColumns="0,2"`
>
> `android:stretchColumns="1"`

[image]

Means column 0 and 2 are wrap contain and column 1 stretch into available width

> `android:stretchColumns="0,1,2"`
>
> `android:shrinkColumns="1"`

[image]

Means if column already stretch then shrink not apply

> `android:shrinkColumns="*"`
>
> `android:collapseColumns="1"`

[image]

android:collapseColumns means it hide given column

> `android:stretchColumns="*"`
>
> `TextView :- android:layout_column="2"`

[image]

Meanning if tablerow first column layout parameter not start with 0 then empty view added into row

> `android:stretchColumns="*"`
>
> `android:collapseColumns="1"`
>
> `TextView :- android:layout_column="2"`

[image]

Means if  tablerow first column layout parameter not start with 0 then empty view added into row  but if you collapse column then added empty view not hide of that column index only hide added view by explicit view

Answer (score 2):

**Shrinking Columns**

We can shrink or reduce the width of the column(s) using the android:shrinkColumns attribute in the TableLayout. We can specify either a single column or a comma delimited list of column numbers for this attribute. The content in the specified columns word-wraps to reduce their width.

**Collapsing Columns**

We can make the column(s) collapse or become invisible through the android:collapseColumns attribute in the TableLayout. We can specify one or more comma-delimited columns for this attribute. These columns are part of the table information but are invisible. We can also make column(s) visible and invisible through coding by passing the Boolean values false and true, respectively, to the setColumnCollapsed() method in the TableLayout

Comment: can you give me an example, please.